# proof for the square root construction

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I know that you can construct a square root of a given segment through a certain construction, and I know that construction.  What is the proof that this construction works to construct a square root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual construction is to make line segments of length $1$ and $x$ on the diameter a semicircle, and extend a vertical line segment up to meet the semicircle. Say the new line segment has length $s$. Then using similar triangles you can show that
$$1:s :: s:x,$$
i.e.,
$$\frac1s = \frac sx,$$
so that $s^2 = x$.