# Heron's Formula Intuitive Geometric Proof

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

This is not the usual request for an intuitive proof, which has been asked already.

Having looked at various sources, I've basically concluded that Heron's formula relies on proving
$$xyz = x+y+z$$
where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the lengths between the meeting point of the incircle and the sides, and the vertices. If I take the diagram below, $x$ is $CX$, and $z$ is $XA$. $y$ would be the segment from $B$ to the incircle meeting the side, marked by a black dot, which is also $YC$. Hence $x+y+z=s$ where $s$ is the semiperimeter.
From here it is easy to show that if the radius ($r$) of the incircle is $1$, then the area of the triangle is $x+y+z$. The radius does not really matter, because when it comes to proving the formula, you can just proportionally reduce the size of the triangle by a factor of $1/r^2$. So we can work with the $r=1$ case.

Proving $xyz = x+y+z$ visually is not difficult by looking at this diagram:
http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/Heron/Heron2/Heron2.html
[image: Heron's formula, University of Georgia page]

When $r = 1$, then $EY = xy$ ($x = (s-c)$ and $y = (s-b)$ since $s = x+y+z$ as defined above) and $EY$ is also equal to $s/z$, so it is conceptually not difficult to show that $x+y+z = xyz$ and from this that $A^2 = (x+y+z)xyz = s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$.

But to my mind, it would be even better if we could show that $xyz$ corresponds to the area of the triangle directly, rather than messing about with equivalences. If we take the $\Delta AYE$ triangle in the above diagram and form a rectangle, whose new vertex we call $P$, and we extend a line from point $X$ to the side $EP$, calling this new vertex $Q$, then $PQXA$ is meant to be of the same area as the triangle, since $XA=z$ and $EY=xy$. Any ways to prove that rectangle $PQXA$ is equivalent to triangle $\Delta ABC$? Or perhaps there's a better way to prove  $xyz$ corresponds to the area of the triangle $\Delta ABC$?

Cheers

Comment: Please use mathjax to put the text of the question in a better shape. (As it is, it is not really friendly readable.) https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Mathjax is close to latex, and this is indispensable for any mathematician and/or any mathematical text.

Comment: OK, i edited and inserted the picture...

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  For a start, just enclose all mathematical expression in `$` signs. `$A^2 = (x+y+z)xyz = s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$` shows up as $A^2 = (x+y+z)xyz = s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll use mathjax from now on.

Comment: I don't understand what $x$, $y$, and $z$ are.  Th  Can you say specifically the length from which point to which point is $x$, for example?

Comment: @Derek   if you have a reply for a specific comment, begin it with an at sign @ and at least the first three letters of that username. It should prompt you, you may click on the full username. If you don't do that, a user who has left this question will probably  not be notified of your response back here.

Comment: I don't know what kind of proof you would consider acceptable, but let me notice that $xyz$ has dimensions of volume, hence to become an area it must be divided by $r$. In other words: some kind of ratio must be involved.

Comment: @Batominovski Tell me if it's still unclear.

Comment: @Aretino Not necessarily. As demonstrated, you can get segments which are multiples of other segments' lengths. In this case for example, triangles $CXI$ and $CYE$ are similar, so if $r=1$, then $\frac{EY}{YC}=CX$. So $EY=YC*CX$ without being two dimensional.

Comment: First of all, you need seriously
take care of the mess you did with the units.
If you state, that  "$x, y$ and $z$ are the lengths",
then the $xyz$ has the units of volume,
while $x+y+z$ is still in length units,
and in this case expression $xyz=x+y+z$
make absolutely no sense, not talking about that 
in other place you state that
" the area of the triangle is $x+y+z$".

Comment: @g.kov You can have a segment length equivalent to the numerical value of the product of two other segments. You can even find a segment that is the square root of a given length: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587420/proof-for-the-square-root-construction) This does not mean that units are half dimensional.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, let's rectify the dimensionality issues by refraining from setting $r=1$.

With liberal re-labeling of the figure ...

[image]

... we have

$$\left.\begin{array}{cr}
\triangle A'E'C\sim\triangle CEI \to & \dfrac{h}{s-b} =\dfrac{s-c}{r} \\[6pt]
\triangle A'E'A\sim\triangle IEA \to & \dfrac{h}{s} = \dfrac{r}{s-a} 
\end{array}\right\}\to \frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{r}=h=\frac{rs}{s-a} \tag{1}$$
so that
$$(s-a)(s-b)(s-c) = s r^2 \tag{2}$$

Now, one may read the right-hand side of $(2)$ as $|\triangle ABC|^2/s$, so that $|\triangle ABC|^2=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$; that's Heron. OP prefers to interpret the right-hand side as $|\triangle ABC|\,r$, and thus seeks to establish directly that
$$|\triangle ABC| = \frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{r} \tag{3}$$

In particular, since $h=(s-b)(s-c)/r$ (via $(1)$), OP suggests showing $(3)$ via a demonstration that $|\triangle ABC|=h(s-a)$, perhaps by treating the product as twice the area of a triangle with base $s-a$ and height $h$. While OP considers introducing a rectangle, there's a more-natural option:

[image]

A little angle-chasing shows that the marked angles at $B$ and $F$ are congruent, as are those at $C$ and $E$. Thus,

$$\left.\begin{array}{r}
\overline{A'B}\parallel\overline{DF}\;\to\;|\triangle A'DF|=|\triangle BDF| \\
\overline{A'C}\parallel\overline{DE}\;\to\;|\triangle A'DE|=|\triangle CDE|
\end{array}\right\}\;\to\;
\begin{align} \\ \\ |\triangle ABC| &= \phantom{2}\;|\square AFA'E| \\ &=2\;|\triangle AA'E| \\ &= \phantom{2}\;|AE|\;|A'E'|\end{align}
\tag{$\star$}$$
as desired. $\square$

---

It's also worth noting that $|\triangle ABC|=h(s-a)=\frac12h(-a+b+c)$ follows immediately from $A'$'s role as an excenter (being equidistant from the side-lines of $\triangle ABC$):
$$|\triangle ABC|+|\triangle A'BC|  = |\square ABA'C| = |\triangle AA'C|+|\triangle AA'B|$$
$$\begin{align}\to\quad |\triangle ABC| &= -|\triangle A'BC|+|\triangle AA'C|+|\triangle AA'B| \\[4pt] 
&=-\tfrac12ha+\tfrac12hb+\tfrac12hc \\[4pt]
&=\phantom{-}\tfrac12h(-a+b+c)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Brilliant result! Thanks a lot.