# Is there an intuitive way to explain this result?

Tags: geometry, triangles

In [this](https://rb.gy/wrrha8) answer, the writer presents a beautiful proof of Heron's formula.

[image]
(Source: the same answer)

The identity written $x+y+z=xyz$, which he proved by the use of similar triangles and some algebra.

How can I explain this intuitively to someone who doesn't know similar triangles? And/or is there some intuition behind this formula that makes it look easy to observe how this comes?

Comment: Related: ["Heron's Formula Intuitive Geometric Proof"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3752471/409). The question itself gives a visual demonstration of the relation $x+y+z=xyz$, taken from [this page (via uga.edu)](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/Heron/Heron2/Heron2.html), although similar triangles are involved. (Avoiding similarity altogether is a pretty big ask.)

Comment: @Blue: That proof helped a lot and in my opinion, I think I will be able to explain that to the students (I'm just a schooler, but I like to teach maths to my juniors), and there is even no algebra there, so it's very intuitive. Thanks a lot :D, although I think I might put this open, who knows someone might be able to explain it ;)